# get all mysql entries out of of one table which are not in another specific table

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I have 2 tables. One looks like this (it contains more fields, but that should not matter):

```
TABLE 'containers';
INT id;
VARCHAR(20) name;
VARCHAR(20) uid;

TABLE 'sync';
INT id;
VARCHAR(20) containerUid;
VARCHAR(20) deviceUid;
```

Now i need to get all containers, that do not have an entry in 'sync'-table for one specific deviceUid. I tried it this way, but the result does not seem correct.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sync AS b WHERE a.uid = b.containerUid AND b.deviceUid = 'DEVICEUID') AS anzahlSync FROM containers AS a) AS A WHERE anzahlSync = 0
```

I want to do this in mysql, because containers-table contains a lot of entries. So I try not to get them back as result, but filter them before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select *
from containers c
where not exists (select 1 from sync s where s.containerUid = c.id and s.deviceUid = 'DEVICEUID')
```

Comment: That was what I had been looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cover also entries that are NULL in one of the both tables you can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM containers
        WHERE name LIKE 'DEVICEUID'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT id, containerUid as name, deviceUid as uid
        FROM sync
        WHERE name LIKE 'DEVICEUID'
    ) AS diff
GROUP BY name, uid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```